# Error Message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean in sql sever 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Bit columns store a 1 or a 0.

Entering 1 or 0 in a bit column gives the ERROR:

> Invalid value for cell (row 42, column 17).
>
> The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid. .Net
>   Framework Data Type: Boolean Error Message: String was not recognized
>   as a valid Boolean.
>
> Type a value appropriate for the data type or press ESC to cancel the
>   change.

How can 1 or 0 NOT be a valid boolean?

Bit fields should allow 1 or 0.

Comment: To answer your question *How can 1 or 0 NOT be a valid boolean?* - pretty easily, 1 or 0 are integers, try this in c# for example: `bool b = 1;`, it won't even compile. To solve your problem you will probably need to post more information.

Comment: when i tried to insert 0 or 1 in a boolean value in sql server 2008. it wont inserted it will throw the error.. instead tat you have the enter true as 1 and false as 0

Comment: SQL Server does not have a boolean datatype, it has `BIT` which allows 1 or 0. Your error (as indicated by the message) is coming from the .NET framework, where you can't convert 1 or 0 to a boolean.

Comment: Then what's the point of bool.Parse? Isn't the whole purpose of parse to take something in a different format and convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah i encountered this problem a lot, when i tried to insert 0 or 1 in a boolean value in sql server 2008...

To fix it, i used BIT type as a boolean type:
The BIT Type takes 2 values:

**If you want to insert 0 then you have to type "False" value
else if you want to insert 1 then you have to type "True" value**

then if you want to use BIT value as int then use `CAST(BITFIELD as int)` it will convert it to 0 or 1

I hope it helped...